# Google Oauth2 Client ID not found in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oauth-2.0, calendar

I'm trying to connect to the Google Calendar API using rails, but it keeps telling me `Missing required parameter: client_id` Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Code:

**omniauth.rb**

```
    Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY'],
  {
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar, hidden@gmail.com'
  }
end
```

**secrets.yml**

```
    development:
  secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxx
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: xxxxxxx
  GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY: xxxxx

test:
  secret_key_base: xxxxxxx



production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

**development.rb**

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID         = Rails.application.secrets.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY        = Rails.application.secrets.GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY
```

I also have a client_secrets.json file that has the downloaded code from Google.

Comment: Its not a good idea to post your api keys, you should just replace with anything like `xxxxx`

Comment: Got ya. Thanks a lot

Comment: can you log the requests and see if the keys are being used?

Comment: Not sure if I went to the right place, but I checked the network tab in Google console and looked at request header and query string parameters and didn't see it anywhere

Comment: hmm I believe you should have those passed in there

Comment: The Ruby constant `ENV` accesses your environmental variables. Are you setting your keys there?

Comment: If you are not already doing that then you can use https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv to manage your `environment` variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, I'd advise you to regenerated new secrets: everyone can still see your keys using the edit option in SO.

But to answer your question, there is no need to do some kind of passing through using globals, you can simply access your secrets in the omniauth initializer (`config/initializers/omniauth.rb`):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, Rails.application.secrets.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, Rails.application.secrets.GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY
end
```

I hope your indent in the `config/secrets.yml` file is by accident, `development:` should be on a tab/double space before its values:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxx
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: xxxxxxx
  GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY: xxxxx

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: <%= ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"] %>
  GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY: <%= ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY"] %>
```

Personally I like my YAML keys to be lowercased, but I guess that is just something of a personal preference.